# Having trouble understanding Json_normalize Record_path argument

Tags: python, json, pandas, api, dictionary

So from the pandas documentation:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html

```
data = [
    {
        "state": "Florida",
        "shortname": "FL",
        "info": {"governor": "Rick Scott"},
        "counties": [
            {"name": "Dade", "population": 12345},
            {"name": "Broward", "population": 40000},
            {"name": "Palm Beach", "population": 60000},
        ],
    },
    {
        "state": "Ohio",
        "shortname": "OH",
        "info": {"governor": "John Kasich"},
        "counties": [
            {"name": "Summit", "population": 1234},
            {"name": "Cuyahoga", "population": 1337},
        ],
    },
]
result = pd.json_normalize(
    data, "counties", ["state", "shortname", ["info", "governor"]]
)
result
         name  population    state shortname info.governor
0        Dade       12345   Florida    FL    Rick Scott
1     Broward       40000   Florida    FL    Rick Scott
2  Palm Beach       60000   Florida    FL    Rick Scott
3      Summit        1234   Ohio       OH    John Kasich
4    Cuyahoga        1337   Ohio       OH    John Kasich
```

My question is what is the record_path argument doing exactly?
From what I understand the record_path is specifying to a list of records, but then we are also getting records from state,shortname etc as features in the dataframe.
So what is the difference between record_label and meta arguments?

P.S.I looked into other Stackoverflow posts but didnt quite understand.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`record_path` specific the list of items to base the actual rows on.

As you can see below, when you omit the `meta` (3rd argument), the rows are just the properties from the objects in the list you specified, `counties`:

```
>>> pd.json_normalize(data, record_path="counties")
         name  population
0        Dade       12345
1     Broward       40000
2  Palm Beach       60000
3      Summit        1234
4    Cuyahoga        1337
```

Those correspond directly to object in `countries`:

```
...
"counties": [
    {"name": "Dade", "population": 12345},
    {"name": "Broward", "population": 40000},
    {"name": "Palm Beach", "population": 60000},
]
...
"counties": [
    {"name": "Summit", "population": 1234},
    {"name": "Cuyahoga", "population": 1337},
],
...
```

`meta` specifies properties from the JSON you pass (`data`) to add to the records specified by `records_path`.